# os.path.basename(path) what does "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'path'" mean?

Tags: python, path

I am trying to use `os.path.basename(path)` on a string. I thought that was how it was used. In the [doc for version 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) it clearly says that is the case but I am using 2.7. How do I use the method if all I have is a string (which clearly don't have a path attribute?)

Comment: Quick overshadowing check: what does `print(type(os))` output?

Comment: oh... gah scary! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have overridden `os` with your own variable.

Something like this:

```
import os
# ...
os = "abc"
# ...
os.path # <-- error
```

Make sure you don't [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) imported libraries.